# How should I initialize an array of classes with a default (parameterless) constructor in Java?

Tags: java

How should I initialize an array of classes with an empty constructor?

I can see that if I was using the constructor I would do it like so -

```
MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[] {
    new MyClass(1),
    new MyClass(2),
    new MyClass(3)
};
```

But with an empty constructor I'm not sure what to do.

```
MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[] {
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass(),
    new MyClass()
};
```

This is what I have at the moment, but it seems terribly inefficient - is there a better way?

(I called it MyClass / myArray for readability in the example - don't worry, I do use sensible variable names!)

Comment: With only three members it's not really inefficient.  How many do you actually expect to have?

Comment: How is it inneficient?  Do you mean inneficient to program since you have to type all the `new MyClass` or do you think it's doing to much work at runtime?

Comment: Do you need to have three different instances of the class?

Comment: Why you consider the first as efficient and the second as inefficient?

Comment: Do you really mean "empty constructor"? Or a default (or parameter less) constructor. That's kind of confusing.

Comment: Ah sorry - clarifications - 

- There are 14 members in the real array
- I mean inefficient to program 
- I need to have 14 instances, they are to track athletes individually but information such as their name is entered by the user later so no variables are set on initialization
- The first is efficient because if you need to pass a variable into the constructor, you need to do it and there is no way around that; the second is inefficient because they are all the same and no variable is being passed

Comment: could you please close the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either have to write them out one at a time, or you have to use a loop:

```
MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[n];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i) {
    myArray[i] = new MyClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> T[] getArray(final Class<? extends T> memberclass, final int numberOfItems) {

    final T[] array = new T[numberOfItems];
    final Constructor constr = memberclass.getConstructor(null);
    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++) {
        array[index] = constr.newInstance(null);
    }

    return array;
}
```

This would a *rough* draft for a generic method that you can use for that purpose. Of course, I skipped all the exception handling, so this method would bloat a bit more in reality.